# Working with multiple dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping, multiple-columns

I am new to python, please help me to fix this problem.

I have two dataframe as:

```
DF1       |        DF2

Name      |       Name Price Colour    
AB        |        AB    15     red
BC        |        BC    20     white
TB        |        TB    23     blue
QT        |        QT    52     orange
YU        |        YU    55     pink
```

I want to create a 3rd dataframe as (please let me know how do I get it) :

```
AB_Price  AB_Colour BC_Price  BC_Colour   TB_Price   TB_Colour  QC_Price  QC_Colour   YU_Price   YU_Colour
15         red        20        white      23           blue       52       Orange      55         pink
```

I have tried Transpose method in pandas but it is not giving me the desired output.
Please help me how will I get the 3rd dataframe as my final desired output.

Comment: what is the purpose of DF1?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use `df1` as a list of Names to keep in `df2`, and reshape `df2`, combine [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), then [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and flatten the MultiIndex with [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.swaplevel.html) and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html):

```
df3 = (df2
 .loc[df2['Name'].isin(df1['Name'])]
 .assign(index=df2.groupby('Name').cumcount())
 .pivot(index='index', columns='Name')
 .sort_index(level='Name', axis=1)
 .rename_axis(index=None)
)

df3.columns = df3.columns.swaplevel().map('_'.join)
print(df3)
```

Output:

```
  AB_Colour  AB_Price BC_Colour  BC_Price QT_Colour  QT_Price TB_Colour  TB_Price YU_Colour  YU_Price
0       red        15     white        20    orange        52      blue        23      pink        55
```